# ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> in Parcelable object kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, kotlin, parcelable

Array of arrays of strings needs to be parcelized. The object is like so

```
data class Foo (
    @SerializedName("bar") val bar: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>,
)
```

It doesn't exactly need to be ArrayList. Array can also used.

```
data class Foo (
    @SerializedName("bar") val bar: Array<Array<String>>,
)
```

Whichever easier is ok to map this json data

```
{
  "bar": [
    ["a", "b"],
    ["a1", "b2", "c2"],
    ["a3", "b34", "c432"]
  ]
}
```

Using kotlin experimental `Parcelize` crashes the app when it's compiled with progaurd

How is it written in "writeToParcel" and read in "constructor"?

```
data class Foo (
  @SerializedName("bar") val bar: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>,
) : Parcelable {

  constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
     // ?????
  )

  override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
    // ?????
  }

}
```

Comment: use serializable for solve this complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly create `Parcelable` for `List` of `List` directly, so one solution is to make one subclass of your desired `List` as `Parcelable` and take it as you final list type. *How?* check out below :

**Let's first create our internal List of String class like below :**

```
class StringList() : ArrayList<String>(), Parcelable {
    constructor(source: Parcel) : this() {
        source.createStringArrayList()
    }

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeStringList(this@StringList)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<StringList> = object : Parcelable.Creator<StringList> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): StringList = StringList(source)
            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<StringList?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

What we've done here is created our `ArrayList<String>` parcelable so that we can use it at any endpoint.

So final data class would be having following implementation :

```
data class Foo(@SerializedName("bar") val bar: List<StringList>) : Parcelable {
    constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
        source.createTypedArrayList(StringList.CREATOR)
    )

    override fun describeContents() = 0

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) = with(dest) {
        writeTypedList(bar)
    }

    companion object {
       @JvmField
       val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Foo> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Foo> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Foo = Foo(source)
            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Foo?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
       }
    }
}
```

*Note: It's simple implementation based on **O.P.**, you can make any customization based on your requirement.*