# Kotlin Add Parcelable implementation for Array of Double

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I'm trying to add the parcelable implementation of a variable declared as an Array of Double.
When I try to generate this implementation automatically with Android Studio, the `coordinates`key stays in TODO:

```
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

class PointGeoJson (
    val type: String = "",
    val coordinates: Array<Double> = emptyArray()
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        TODO("coordinates")
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(type)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<PointGeoJson> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): PointGeoJson {
            return PointGeoJson(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<PointGeoJson?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/yet-another-awesome-kotlin-feature-parcelize-5439718ba220 have a look at the `@Parcelize` annotation

Comment: Please refer to this answer, it might be helpful in your case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55057334/10271334

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class PointGeoJson(
        val type: String = "",
        val coordinates: Array<Double> = emptyArray()
) : Parcelable
```

This should work properly